# The sum of 2 numbers is 9 and the product of these same 2 numbers is 20. What is the sum of the squares of these 2 numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The sum of 2 numbers is 9 and the product of these same 2 numbers is 20. What is the sum of the squares of these 2 numbers?

Answer (score 6):

We have $a+b=9,ab=20$

We need $a^2+b^2$ which equals to $(a+b)^2-2\cdot ab$

Answer (score -1):

if you want to find the values of $a$ and$b$ and further solve.$a$ and $b$ are the roots of the quadratic equation $$x^2-(a+b)x+ab=0$$ie$$x^2-9x+20=0$$which are$5$ and$4$.   further $4^2+5^2=41$

Comment: I would guess that the point of the exercise is to show that you can get the answer *without* solving the quadratic. To find $a^2+b^2$, you do not have to find $a$ and $b$.

Comment: i just tried to give another answer!!!

Comment: Sure. I downvoted only because the grammar and formatting are so sloppy, and I expect that was the reason for the other down-vote, too. A tip for you: if you want your answers to have credibility, you should write them more carefully. You're not writing a text message to your buddy, you're writing a formal answer to a mathematical question that will be read and reviewed by a sophisticated and knowledgeable audience. Appearance matters.